# why compiler is not showing error when I have two functions one will take base class and one will take derived class as parameters?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

I have a base class and a derived class which is derived from base class. Each one has a friend function which is overloading `operator+` as below.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class base
{
    private:
        int x;

    public:
        base(int a) : x(a)
        {
        }

        void printx()
        {
            cout << "x : " << x << endl;
        }

        friend void operator+(int data, base &obj);
};

void operator+(int data, base &obj)
{
    obj.x = data + obj.x;
}

class derived : public base
{
    private:
        int y;

    public:
        derived(int a, int b) : base(a), y(b)
        {
        }

        void printy()
        {
            cout << "y : " << y << endl;
        }

        friend void operator+(int data, derived &obj);
};

void operator+(int data, derived &obj)
{
    operator+(data, obj);
    obj.y = data + obj.y;
}

int main()
{
    derived c(2, 3);

    4 + c;

    c.printx();
    c.printy();
}
```

I thought compiler will throw error because of the friend functions.

```
void operator+(int data, base &obj)
void operator+(int data, derived &obj)
```

The function that will take a base class object as parameter can also take a derived class object as base is part of derived class. So I thought the compiler will show an error as both functions can take derived class object as parameter. But this program is working fine. Can any one please explain why the compiler is not showing an error?

Comment: downvoter. Please let me know what is wrong with this question.

Comment: Maybe because the question is too simple and only worth a few minutes' searching?

Comment: Exceptions are thrown. Errors are shown. Don't misuse standard terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simple answer**: The two functions does not conflict because they do not have the same signature.

When you call one with a base instance, it won't fit into the derived class reference, so `operator+(int, base&)` will be called.

When you call one with a derived instance, the base function requires an implicit conversion, whereas the derived function doesn't, so `operator+(int, derived&)` will be called.

Reference: Function [Overload Resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution), See the *Viable function* and *Best viable function* sections.

> 1) there is at least one argument of F1 whose implicit conversion is better than the corresponding implicit conversion for that argument of F2

Of course *no implicit conversion* is "better" than one implicit conversion, then `operator+(int, base&)` won't be called for a devired object.

Answer (score 1):

For `4 + c;`, [overload resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) will try to select the best one; `operator+(int data, derived &obj)` is an exact match, `operator+(int data, base &obj)` requires an implicit conversion (from `derived` to `base`), then `operator+(int data, derived &obj)` is selected and no ambiguity error here.